# Haskell numeric list processing

Tags: haskell

I am having trouble finishing this problem. Any hints to a possible solution will be appreciated.

Given a `Double` value `v` and a list of `Double` values `xs`, `calcList` returns a list of `Double`s
according to the following rules:

1. For each value `x` in `xs`, if `x` is not positive, there will be no corresponding value in the output list.
2. Otherwise, the corresponding output value will be `x * ln x`.
3. However, this value will be in the output list if and only if its value is greater than `v`.
4. The order of the corresponding output values (if present) should be the same as the input
   values.

The followings are some examples:

```
calcList 1.0 [] = []
calcList 1.0 [3.0] = [3.2958]
calcList 1.0 [-1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 9.0] = [3.2958, 8.0472, 13.6214, 19.7750]
calcList 100.0 [1.0 .. 40.0] = [102.0359, 106.4536, 110.9035, 115.3847, 119.8963, 124.4372, 129.0067, 133.6040, 138.2283, 142.8789, 147.5552]
```

This what I have so far:

```
positive :: Double -> Bool
positive x = x > 0.0

calcValue :: Double -> Double
calcValue x = log x * x

calcList :: Double -> [Double] -> [Double]
calcList v xs = []
calcList v xs
```

Comment: Though one possible answer uses higher order functions, there are also solutions that do not. I have removed that tag, and several others like it that describe only a subset of possible solutions (hence are not inherent to the question).

Answer (score 5):

So it looks like there are 3 steps.

1. Get rid of elements <= 0 (`filter`)
2. Multiply each remaining elements by its natural log (`map`)
3. Get rid of elements <= `v` (`filter`)

Instead of applying these each to an input, we can compose the functions using `(.)` (since`f.g == \x -> f (g x)`).

```
calcList = \v -> filter (>v) . map (\x -> x*log x) . filter (>0)
```

You should checkout the docs on [`filter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) and [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map). Also [this chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions) from **Learn You A Haskell** would be a good read.

Comment: According to preference, it can also be written as a list comprehension `calcList v xs = [xLogX | x <- xs, x > 0, let xLogX = x * log x, xLogX > v]` or in `do` notation `calcList v xs = do { x <- xs; guard (x > 0); let xLogX = x * log x; guard (xLogX > v); pure v }`. I like your version with composition the best, though, because it’s slightly more flexible for future modification and factoring.

Comment: What would this Haskell code look like as a python list comprehension?

Comment: @AnthonyParker `[a for a in [x * np.log(x) for x in xs if x > 0] if a > v]`.

Answer (score 2):

We can use an approach where we use functions like `filter`, and `map`. An equivalent solution can be obtained with *list comprehension*:

```
calcList :: (Ord d, Floating d) => d -> [d] -> [d]
calcList v xs = [xlogx | x <- xs, x > 0, let xlogx = x * log x, xlogx > v]
```

We thus here use `x <- xs` to iterate over the elements in `xs`, by using `x > 0` we filter values such that only values where `x > 0` are considered. Next we define a variable `xlogx` as `let xlogx = x * log x`, and then we have an extra filter that checks if `xlogx > v`.

The yield part of the list comprehension (the part before the pipe char `|`) specifies that we add `xlogx` to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be

```
calcList :: Double -> [Double] -> [Double]
calcList v [] = []
calcList v (x:xs) = case (positive x) of {
                   False -> calcList v xs;
                   True -> case ((calcValue x) > v) of {
                            False -> calcList v xs;
                            True -> (calcValue x):(calcList v xs);
                   };
}
```

In each of the `cases` you check for one of the conditions, plus you add the numbers at the beginning of the list so the order will be the same.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the use of brackets and semicolons in Haskell.

Comment: I think it would be much more idiomatic to write something like `if positive x && calcValue x > v then ... else ...`.